# Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\myProject\app\build\intermediates\builds

Tags: android

when I want to run my project  in a real device using android studio,I've got this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

> Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\myProject\app\build\intermediates\builds

how can I resolve it.?
Furthermore, R is red in all class files, I cleaned and rebuilt the project but nothing happened!

Comment: Close all command prompts (if any opened), close Android studio and open it again and try the build step.

Comment: Did you previously had some problems? Maybe there's still a process running that has that directory open? And (a little cliched I know, but...) have you tried restarting your computer and tried again?

Comment: @Nambari: I restarted he android studio and rebuilt the project, nothing happened

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened?

Comment: @Some programmer dude,I have not got this error but usually after I uninstall the app from my device and rerun it, R is red and android studio can not resolve it. restarting the PC is not worked

Comment: @Nambari: I mean I still have this problem.

Comment: I have another question, how can I use this command in my root directory:
./gradlew clean

Comment: Ok as @Someprogrammerdude said, restart the computer and see, it seems some process got a lock on that directory, still doesn't work, change that particular directory permissions.

Comment: it doesn't work for me....

Comment: I get that now and then and generally if I delete the directory from outside Android Studio and run the build again everything works.

Comment: @nasch I can't delete that builds folder outside the android studio, The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Try Unlocker, it might be able to help. I think it's here: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlocker.html

Comment: @nasch: I use windows. unlocker doesnt work for me, I mean when I right click on builds folder and choose unlocker and delete, unlocker doesn't delete that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, very simple solution is close Android Studio and reopen as administrator. Right click on Android Studio icon and click "run as administrator". Window require administrator permission to remove the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost nothing worse than restarting an app (Netbeans) or rebooting and still having the same error. So try this:

Click the error message (it's a link):

Exactly what does the line linked to say? Copy several lines around the one linked to and report back.

It might be easy to fix

---

Looking ahead..

Depending on what you tell us, I might suggest that you:

(1) save or make a copy of the project;

**(2a)** make a copy of the line linked to and note its line number and

(2b) make a copy of the `xml` file in the message and note both its name and the folder it's in;

**(3)** delete the line linked to and

**(4)** recompile.

**(5)** Make the `xml` look like it was before you deleted the line.

No harm done.

If it were me, I'd only do the **bold** steps above.

If the folder that the error refers to is **not** empty, it's more complicated. But whenever I get this similar error, it is.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me today. I tried with **Clean Project** but it doesn't work. The only solution worked for me is

**File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart**

It rebuilds the projects and also restart the android.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that I have the room database in my project and get this error when rebuilding project. I have tried to open Android studio in admin mode but the error has been there. The invalidate cache and restart option has not help me as well. I finally had to delete the build folder manually then rebuild the project and the error has gone.

Remember that you have to close all programs running on the files in build folder such as Open JDK, emulator, etc. before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

if using `Microsoft Windows` open `Task Manager` find the `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` and `End Task`

Now `Clean Project` or `Rebuild Project`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

just for record.. today, i faced with that issue. i couldn't delete that folder manually but i tried to cut and past it somewhere outside the project, then the  program worked